# i'm in Trouble with Nested Master Page :(

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

how to use nested Master Pages in Asp.net ? i'm facing an error of nullrefrence exception on every **nested master page** control? can you please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

on PageLoad Binding a label

`secondMasterTesting.Text = "Hello World form Second Master";`

here is my base master page top:

`<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="BluePumpkin.MasterPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>`

and my **nestedMaster** Page here from top:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Admin.master.cs" Inherits="BluePumpkin.AdminPanel.Admin" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `secondMasterTesting` is probably hidden because is either inside `ContentPlaceHolder` or you call it from some other page than the one the control is registered.

To solve the error try

```
if(secondMasterTesting != null)
  secondMasterTesting.Text = "Hello World form Second Master";
```

The code behind is search on belonging page for that control.

Comment: Problem solved , that was my own basic mistake! because i'm very new to master pages....By the Thanks.....